# How to check if a Firestore field is of type Timestamp?

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, timestamp, clojurescript, coercion

Without knowing ahead of time what I'm going to get from Firestore, how do I check if a field coming out of Firestore is a Timestamp?

Answer (score 2):

This is valid for [Timestamp in Firebase SDK v9](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firestore_.timestamp.md#timestamp_class)

```js
> import { Timestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';
> yourVariable instanceof Timestamp

true
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
import firebase from 'firebase/app';

export const isTimestamp = (
  timestamp: any
): timestamp is firebase.firestore.Timestamp => {
  return (
    typeof timestamp === "object" && timestamp.seconds && timestamp.nanoseconds
  );
};

// Usage:
if (isTimestamp(someData.createdAt)) {
   return moment.unix(someData.createdAt.seconds).format(...);
}
```